# How to Cast a section of a byte array to a specific type?

Tags: c++, arrays, sockets, networking, casting

I need to build a byte buffer to send over a socket.

I have the following structs

```
struct
{
   int a;
   char b;
} header; //5bytes

struct
{
    char x;
    char y[3];
} B; //4bytes
```

and the byte array

```
uint8_t bytes[30];
```

The first part would be `header`

```
((header*)&bytes)->a = 32;
```

etc.  No problem.

But then I'd like to do something like

```
((B*)&bytes[sizeof(header)])->x = 12;
```

casting the portion of `bytes` that'd be after `header` and assigning the values.

Can this be done?  Is there a better way?

Edit:

About hton & endianness: I know about this.  That would come after setting the buffer before calling the "send" command.

Comment: Is this C, C++, or something else?

Comment: @jwodder C++.  Forgot to tag

Comment: Did you mean to write `((B*)&bytes[sizeof(header)])->x = 12;`?

Comment: Stop before you start. Don't use `struct` or `class` as network protocols. Use network protocols as network protocols. Start by defining the protocol, in octets, and then write yourself a *library*, i.e. *code*, to send and receive it. Your way introduces half a dozen dependencies you don't want in your system.

Answer (score 0):

`((header*)bytes)->a = 32;` is a strict aliasing violation. You can't do anything like that, let alone what you tried after that.

Instead you should set individual bytes of `bytes`. For example:

```
uint8_t *ptr = &bytes[0];

memcpy( ptr, &temp, sizeof temp );
ptr += sizeof temp;

*ptr++ = 12;
```

For more information look up *serialization*.  Also look up *endianness*.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ yes, forgetting ampersands everywhere

Answer (score 0):

> I need to build a byte buffer to send over a socket.

You'll face problems with direct c-style (`reinterpret_cast`) casts, when the structures are interpreted at different host machine architectures.

`int` values may be interpreted regarding different endianess and thus cannot be casted from the underlying bytes correctly.

The usual salvage is to use the functions from the [`htonx()`/`ntohx()` family](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/htonl.html) to en-/decode those integer values.

Another way to go is to use a generic message protocol like [google protocol buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/).

Comment: I know about the byteswapping. That is also why I'm curious about this, so I can byteswap fields by their name instead of having to worry about exactly how many bytes into the data buffer they are.  This construction of a buffer is what the receiver will expect, a header and then some predetermined data dependent on what's in the header. But it all has to be packaged in one unit for the "send" of course.

Comment: @MikeDannyboy _"That is also why I'm curious about this, so I can byteswap fields by their name instead of having to worry about exactly how many bytes into the data buffer they are."_ The closest I can point you regarding that is google protobuf, or some other de-/serialization helper library, that covers the endianess aspect transparently.